# Filtering list comprehension inside another list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Here is my current code:

```py
[[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in table.find_all('tr')]
```

What I'm doing, essentially, is to parse the output of a BeautifulSoup + Requests fetched table from a webpage. Regardless of the purpose, the portion `[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]` gives me a list representing a row, and it works fine. What I would want, though, is to filter this list, to remove rows where the first element is the empty string. So, my code would turn into

```py
[[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in table.find_all('tr') if [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')][0] != ""
```

which is sad and horrible. I'm coming from a background of functional programming in Scala, so using map, filter and reduce operations are just fine for me, but, in Python, they return `map object` instead of a proper list, so there is another `List(map(lambda: ...))`, which makes the code look really bad with tons of parenthesis here and there, to each high order function call.

Is there a pythonic way to do this, while still maintaining readability?
I'm almost going down to simple `.append()` to make this readable, despite not looking pythonic at all to me.

Edit: I really need a list of lists, because I will perform this many times, reading multiple tables, and then maybe append them all, so please don't try to change that part of the code structure.

Edit 2: This is my current unfiltered output. My goal is to filter out the first two rows.

```
[
 ['', '', '', ''],
 ['', '', 'Taxas de juros'],
 ['Posição', 'Instituição', '% a.m.', '% a.a.'],
 ['1', 'SINOSSERRA S/A - SCFI', '0,41', '5,03'],
 ['2', 'GRAZZIOTIN FINANCIADORA SA CFI', '0,84', '10,55'],
 ['3', 'BCO CATERPILLAR S.A.', '0,89', '11,27'],
 ['4', 'BCO VOLKSWAGEN S.A', '0,91', '11,49']
]
```

Comment: Do you realise a map object is iterable? But you can only consume it once.

Comment: Can you use css selectors? not sure off hand but something like `table.find_all(tr :not(td:first-child:empty))` (I'm not a css guy too often..)

Comment: I know it is iterable, but I need a list, because I intend to use it further on my code in other libs (as pandas).

As for the css, it will not work, because my row is a string - I'm converting it to a list using the strip method. I would need to filter by the first string character, which worsens my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
[[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] 
 for tr in table.find_all('tr') 
 if tr.find('td').text.strip()]
```

Because `tr.find('td')` will return the first child `td`. And the stripped text of that will either have length or it won't. And in Python, a string with a length greater than 0 evaluates to True.

Comment: Please see my edit. You seem to have understood that the row would be completely empty, which is not the case. I need to filter out by the first position of the returned row. There will be no empty string - a filterable row will be like `", , , "`, which is not well covered by your code, if I'm reading it well.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed, and I don't understand why. I read it wrong the first time.

Comment: I got it now. Accepting answer. Thank you! Really sleek.

Answer (score 1):

In 2 passes it would be enough to do:

```
lst = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in table.find_all('tr')]
[i for i in lst if i[0] != '']
```

to get:

```
[['Posição', 'Instituição', '% a.m.', '% a.a.'],
 ['1', 'SINOSSERRA S/A - SCFI', '0,41', '5,03'],
 ['2', 'GRAZZIOTIN FINANCIADORA SA CFI', '0,84', '10,55'],
 ['3', 'BCO CATERPILLAR S.A.', '0,89', '11,27'],
 ['4', 'BCO VOLKSWAGEN S.A', '0,91', '11,49']]
```

You can do it in one single pass that way:

```
[i for i in [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
             for tr in table.find_all('tr')] if i[0] != '']
```

Comment: This works, and looks better. I'll just wait to see if I don't see anything "smarter" (not sure what would that be, but anyway), and, otherwise, accept this answer.